# How do I deploy a flask server directly to Azure

Tags: python, azure, flask

I needed some help to host a website using Azure Resource Groups -> Web
It is a flask backend with nltk and has API keys.
The frontend is simple html and css.

I have put the source code onto github, and tried to deploy it directly from there, but it doesnt seem to work. If anyone has any experience with it, please help me out!

The error is as follows:
App Directory Location: '/' was found.
Looking for event info
The content server has rejected the request with: BadRequest
Reason: No matching Static Web App was found or the api key was invalid.

Comment: Let me google that for you... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-python?tabs=flask%2Cwindows%2Cazure-cli%2Cvscode-deploy%2Cdeploy-instructions-azportal%2Cterminal-bash%2Cdeploy-instructions-zip-azcli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **As per the comment by @Silent you can follow this [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-python?tabs=flask,windows,azure-cli,vscode-deploy,deploy-instructions-azportal,terminal-bash,deploy-instructions-zip-azcli) and Deploy Flask app to Azure web app, I have followed the same steps from the above document below:-**

I have cloned the repository from the Document and Opened it in my Vs Code, I have Azure extension installed in my Vs Code.
I selected the extension and clicked on Deploy to Web app like below:-

> [image]

Select Azure extension and click on Deploy to Web app like below:-

[image]

Select your Web app like below and the deployment will start

[image]

Deployment was successful like below:-

[image]

> Website Deployed:-
>
> [image]

***In order to deploy the same Code from Github you can directly visit your Azure Web app > Deployment > Deployment Center > Github > Authorize > Login with your Github account and select your repository like below:-***

[image]

[image]

Save the settings and the Deployment of Web app from your github to Azure will begin like below:-

[image]

Deployment from github to Azure Web app got successful like below:-

[image]